# Installing IISPowershellSnapin.26IISPowershellSnapin.exe doesn't succeed

Tags: windows, powershell, iis

I have downloaded the IIS Powershell snapin IISPowershellSnapin.26IISPowershellSnapin.exe

Unfortunately installing on a windows 2012 Remote desktop doesn't succeed.
The error is:

> Microsoft Webinstaller couldn't find the product you tried to install.
>   Either the link you clicked is incorrect or you may be overwriting
>   your feed with different feed.

[image]

I have downloaded it from the site:

> http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/powershell

The manual gives the following Prerequisites:

> The IIS PowerShell Snap-in requires the following prerequisites:
>
> •Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista Service
>   Pack 1, or Windows 7 •Microsoft PowerShell 1.0 or 2.0

So nothing is said about Windows Server 2012.
Is there another executable for Windows Server 2012 or is there another problem.

> http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/installing-the-iis-powershell-snap-in

I have allready checked whether the IIS Management Console is installed and it is installed.

Maybe this executable needs internet connection to install?
On our RDP we have no internet connection so this could be the cause as well.

Answer (score 1):

*Simply don't*. PSSnapIns are obsolete; everything runs on modules now. The IIS Snap-In has been superseded by the WebAdministration module, which provides a superset of functionality.

Install the module on a >2008R2 server with the following PS:

```
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Scripting-Tools
```

This will not cause a service interruption. If it needs a reboot, it will tell you so. You might need to restart your PowerShell console, although this is unnecessary in my experience. After installation, run the cmdlet:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
```